# Regex matching to change ES module import to direct import

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-code, regex-group, regexp-replace

I have a component library package and it's used in a lot of files like this:

```
import { Grid, Heading, Button } from 'component-library'
```

I want to change all of my import to something like this:

```
import { Grid } from 'component-library/lib/Grid'
import { Heading } from 'component-library/lib/Heading'
import { Button } from 'component-library/lib/Button'
```

I found an extension on VSCode for doing this:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=angelomollame.batch-replacer&ssr=false#overview

And it seems it's accepting regex too.
I tried to write a regex to find a replace old imports to a new one but my regex not working. This is my current regex:

```
(?:import)\s+([\w,{}\s\*]+)\s+(?:from)?\s*(?:["'])?([@\w\s\\\/.-]+)(?:["'])?\s*
```

Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: [`(/^\s*import\s*\{((?:\s*\w+,*)+)\s*\}\s*from\s*(['"])([^'"]*)\2\s*;*\s*$/gm)`](https://regex101.com/r/8hfk3D/2) ... would give you for group [1] => ' Grid, Heading, Button
' and for group [3] => 'component-library' ... thus one needs to split the module namespaces of the first matched group, trim each namespace and provide the import syntax for the module name which is matched within the 3rd group ... I do not know, if the plugin supports custom replacement functionality.

Comment: with https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=draivin.hsnips you can add javascript to the snippet

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two steps (that'as good as my regex-fu can do).

Step 1:

`(import \{ )?((\w+)[, ]+)(?=.*?(\} from '(.*)'))`    Search regex

`import { $3 } from '$5/lib/$3'\n`                       Find regex

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mP8jjq/4)

---

This leaves one stray `} from 'great-library';` behind for each original `import` line (maybe someone can improve the regex to avoid that), so remove it with:

`^\} from.*$`  Search

Replace with nothing.

---

There are a few multi-regex replace extensions out there where you can combine these two steps into one.  For example, using [Batch Replacer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=angelomollame.batch-replacer&ssr=false#overview) try this "script":

```
replace-regex "(import { )?((\w+)[, ]+)(?=.*?(} from '(.*)'))"
with "import { $3 } from '$5/lib/$3'\n"

replace-regex "(?<!.)} from.*\r?\n?"
with ""
```

---

[image: Batch Replacer demo]

Answer (score 0):

Without any extensions, just use regular expression as many times as there is a match:

Find:

```
(import\s*{\s*)(\w+)\s*,([\w\s,*]+?)(\s*}(?:\s*from)?\s*)(["'])?([@\w\s\\/.-]*?)\5
```

Replace:

```
$1$2$4$5$6$5\n$1$3$4$5$6$5
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/140ZOq/1)

The pattern will match and capture parts of the pattern into separate groups. Only the first word in the round brackets will be captured each time and a line with just that word will be output + a newline and a line containing other words inside the brackets.

That is why you need to run search and replace until no matches are found.